# Экземпляр класса android.view.window?

Tags: java, android

Как мне создать экземпляр класса Window в андроид, я знаю что можно использовать new Dialog(context).getWindow() или чего-то подобного,
можно ли обойтись без этого?
Какие основные медоты нужно инициализировать?

Comment: Зачем? Не знаю задач, в которых это было бы нужно. Скорее всего у Вас проблема [молотка и микроскопа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/Что-т..)

Comment: Хочу кастомизировать диалоговое окно.

Comment: Ну, Вам создание своего экземпляра window ничего не даст, ведь созданный Вами Window не будет реально связан с дисплеем устройства. В чем проблема использовать Window, который предоставляет диалог?

Comment: Вратце пишу библиотеку на dialog. Осталось сделать затемнение экрана и переопределение метода onBackPressed (или onKeyUp) без помощи пользователя. Какой такой callback мне нужно реализовать? Может KeyEvent.Callback?

Comment: Затемнение экрана делается через стили обычно... onBackPressed в Вашем случае будет вполне логично оставить на пользователя

Comment: Затемнение то да, но у меня работает не совсем как надо. Toolbar не затемняется. какой стиль для этого нужен? использовал background установил его цветом #000000 так правильно?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь использовать вместо диалога вьюху обычную что ли?

Comment: Да что-то типо того, использую контейнер с диалогом, хотел понять как работает dialog с добавлением в менеджер окон и "занимает весь экран с затемнением". Пойду копаться в исходном коде window и dialog. :) Не буду мучать себя и вас ))